# SPARQL insert query

Tags: xml, sparql, rdf, fuseki, turtle-rdf

In turtle I have something like this:

```
@prefix b: <http://www.fake.org/vl/> .

b:ID_13 b:OwnBy b:Katrin ;
    b:Rank   "5" .

b:FID_13 b:OwnBy b:emily ;
    b:Rank "9" ;
    b:Comment "comment \"George goes to school!" ;
    b:Time_Comment "at 10:18 21/01/2015" .
```

when I use

```
SELECT * WHERE{

    ?ID  b:OwnBy  ?Name;
         b:Rank     ?Rank;
}
```

I get as result

```
ID       Name     Rank
ID_13   Katrin    "5"
ID_13   emily     "9"
```

How can I INSERT another rank for ID_13 Katrin (Only for katrin) ????

I have tried this

```
INSERT {b:ID_13 b:Rank  "pppppppppppppp"}

WHERE{b:ID_13 b:OwnBy b:Cathy}
```

But when I use select to see what I have inserted, this query inserts the new rank to both, Katring and emily and then I have the following result:

```
ID       Name     Rank
ID_13   Katrin    "5"
ID_13   Katrin    "pppppppp"
ID_13   emily     "9"
ID_13   emily     "pppppppp"
```

Comment: In your data you have identifiers `b:ID_13` and `b:FID_13`, but the example query results you give suggest that you are using `b:ID_13` for both. Your query result is also either incomplete or inconsistent with the shown query and/or the data.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Actually i don't want to focus on the select query but on the insert. This is a sample of my code in turtle. I have modified the select query for the specific sample. 
Since i have written only 2 registers with the specific ID is normal with the star to get this results.

About the insert. Do you know how can i insert a new triple to ID_13 that ownby catrin only ???

for example if i insert a comment then it will show up only when i select the comments where the name is catrin.

Comment: My point was that you shouldn't edit your example like this, as it introduces problems. Your example as-is is incorrect and does not reproduce the behavior you are describing. This makes it unclear what the precise problem is as we, the readers, do not know if a mistake is in your original data or if it is a mistake in your edited example. 

However, I have made an attempt at an answer, with a few educated guesses on what you are _probably_ trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example data contains two triples with the property `b:OwnBy`:

```
  b:ID_13 b:OwnBy b:Katrin .
  b:ID_13 b:OwnBy b:emily .
```

(I am assuming that the `b:FID_13` in your question is a typo)

Note that both triples share the same subject. Therefore, the resource denoted by `b:ID_13` is owned by both Katrin and emily.

Your `INSERT` operation tries to add a triple `b:ID_13 b:Rank "pppppppppppppp"`. The `WHERE` clause makes no sense as there are no variables to fill in this pattern - it is not precisely wrong, but it doesn't really do anything useful. That aside, what you want to do is simply a logical impossibility. Since `b:ID_13` is a shared subject for both owners `Katrin` and `emily`, you can not insert a rank for `b:ID_13` that does not automatically apply to both `Katrin` and `emily`.

The fault is not your `INSERT` operation, but your input data. You need to make sure that the resources owned by `Katrin` and `emily` do not share the same subject identifier.